# get last data query from calculate and group by

Tags: mysql

i am trying to make trial balance with general ledger data , the results of the trial balance in the can from the last calculation based debit-credit account name, and then group by based on each account name

GEneral ledger : 
Kas :

```
Account  |  Debet  | KRedit  | Saldo 
kas         1000      0        1000
kas         200       0        1200
kas         0         250       950
```

Bank :

```
Account  |  Debet  | KRedit  | Saldo 
bank        2000      0        2000
bank         200       0        2200
bank         0         500      1700
```

Sale :

```
Account  |  Debet  |  KRedit  |   Saldo 
Sale          0        2000      -2000
Sale           0        500       -2500
Sale           0        500       -3000
```

Result :

```
Account  |  Debet  |  KRedit  |    
    Kas       950        0      
    bank      1700      0       
    sale       0        3000
```

There is my code :

```
SELECT nama_perkiraan,kredit,debet,max(@s:=@s+debet-kredit) as saldo FROM `tbl_jurnal_umum` LEFT JOIN (SELECT @s:=0) as `setVar` ON 1=1  GROUP by nama_perkiraan
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    sselect s.account,
         case when s.saldo > 0 then s.saldo else 0 end as debet ,
         case when s.saldo < 0 then s.saldo * -1 else 0 end as kredit 
from
(
select account,
        sum(case when debet <> 0 then debet else kredit * -1 end) saldo
from generalledger
group by account
) s
where s.saldo <> 0
order by 
case when s.account = 'kas' then 1
      when s.account = 'bank' then 2
      else 3
end
```